# How to insert data into subdocument using $push in query, instead of retrieving doc and saving it back

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, subdocument

### Edit: this was actually working

As the [Mongoose - Subdocs: "Adding subdocs"](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) documentation says, we can add a subdoc using the `push` method (i.e. `parent.children.push({ name: 'Liesl' });`)

But I want to go further, and would like to use the `$push` operator to insert subdocuments.

I have two Schemas: the `ThingSchema`:

```
var ThingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

and the `BoxSchema`, the main document that has an array of subdocuments (`things`) of `ThingSchema`:

```
var BoxSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  things: {
    type: [ThingSchema]
  }
});

var BoxModel = mongoose.model('Box', BoxSchema);
```

I need **every subdocument** in `things` to have `unique` names - that is, that it would be impossible to insert a new document into this array that has a `name` value that already exists in the subdocs.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
var thingObj = ... // the 'thing' object to be inserted

BoxModel.update({
  _id: some_box_id, // a valid 'box' ObjectId
  "things.name": { "$ne": thingObj.name }
},
{
  $push: { things: thingObj}
}, 
function(err) {
  if (err) // handle err
  ...
});
```

but not getting any desired results.

What would be the correct way to add a `ThingSchema` subdocument into `BoxSchema`'s `thing` array using the `$push` operator to do so in the query (**must** not add the subdoc if there's another subdoc named the same), instead of the *Mongoose Docs* way?

---

### Edit: this is actually the issue

I made a mistake, the code above works as expected **but** now the problem I have is that when `thingObj` does not match the `ThingSchema`, an empty object is inserted into the `things` array:

```
// now thingObj is trash
var thingObj = { some: "trash", more: "trash" };
```

When executing the query given the above trash object, the following empty object is inserted into the subdocs array:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("an_obj_id") }
```

What I want this case, when the `thingObj` doesn't match the `ThingSchema`, is nothing to be added.

Comment: What you have should technically work I actually can't see anything wrong with it... `"things.name" : { "$ne" : thingObj.name }` is correct. If you try to do a search by just things.name === thingObj.name do you get a result?

Comment: @MarkPieszak you are right, it was actually working! But anyway, it is still not behaving the way I expected. I have just *edited* my question pointing out the remaining issue.

Answer (score 1):

`$addToSet` adds something unique to the array (as in it checks for duplicates). But it only works for primitives.

What you should do is put `things` into their own collection and make a unique index on name. Then, make this change

```
things: {
  type: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'thingscollection'}]
}
```

this way you can do

```
BoxModel.update({
  _id: some_box_id, // a valid 'box' ObjectId
  "things": { "$ne": thingObj._id }
},
{
  $addToSet: { things: thingObj._id}
}, 
function(err) {
  if (err) // handle err
  ...
});
```

And when you fetch use [`.populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) on `things` to get the full documents in there.

It's not exactly how you want it, but that's a design that might achieve what you're aiming for.

Comment: As you said, it is not exactly how I want it. I want to know how to do it the way I have explained.